# SSH tunnelling when using a load balancer and a VM inside a private subnet

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I have a loadbalancer on Azure and a VM in a private subnet. I want to know if it is possible to do ssh port forwarding by using putty to my VM. I have a rule in my load balancer which map port 80 of my load balancer to the same port on one of VMs in the backend pool.

Is it poosile to do ssh tunneling over loadbalancer to a private VM?

Thanks

Comment: SSH is port 22. You could setup a Inbound NAT rule for that if you want the traffic to go to a specific server or just a normal Load balancing rule if you want it more random which backend it goes to.

Comment: Can anyone give me a more detailed answer. I changed the port numbers to 22 on my loadbalancer role but still I cant SSH.

Comment: 1) Validate that the Server is listening to port 22 without LB
2) Read the documentation how to setup the LB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview
3) Setup the LB according to documentation

Saying that "it doesnt work" is nothing we can help you with. You need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can set a NAT Inbound Rule to an ephemeral port and select the VM you want to redirect the ssh traffic. Just remember that the port 22 in the Virtual Machine needs to be open.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).